# Cargar onclick diferentes iframes en diferentes secciones

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo una pagina en la que se encuentran muchos *iframes* pesados en diferentes secciones estoy intentando cargarlos al dar clic ya logre la función.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li').click(function () {
            var url = $(this).attr('rel');
            $('#secc1').attr('src', url);
            $('#secc1').reload();
        });
    });
</script>


<ul>
    <li rel="urlIframe">Link 1</li>
    <li rel="urlIframe">Link 2</li>
    <li rel="urlIframe">Link 3</li>
</ul>
<iframe src="urlIframe" width="100%" height="600px%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="secc1">
</iframe>
```

Ahora mi problema es que al intentar replicar esto mismo cambiándole el *id* seleccionador para poder cargar otros *iframes* en otra sección dentro de la misma página me cambia los *iframes* de la primera sección sin importar el *id*.
Probé dividiendo los archivos y luego llamándolos con

```
<div>
    <?php include "prueba1.php"; ?>
</div>

<div>
    <?php include "prueba2.php"; ?>
</div>
```

Pero sigue sin respetar el *id* del llamado y me carga el contenido en una sección diferente.

¿Alguna sugerencia o idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias

Comment: Amigo,  muy mal muy mal,  es una pesima idea tener mas de 2 o 3 iframes en una misma pagina,  precisamente porque el consumo de recursos de cada iframe dentro de la pagina es absurdo,  por cada iframe se duplica el costo,  haciendo que las paginas web normalmente no puedan renderizar mas de 4 iframes en la misma pagina sin colgarse... hay que mirar otras opciones,  ademas no es tan aconsejable siquiera usar iframe...

Comment: O por lo menos recuerdo una vez en la que tenia 4 iframes pesado y se me reinicio el pc varias vecez haciendo pruebas a ver si podia de alguna manera optimizar el consumo de recursos de casa iframe.